# How to integrate a vanilla Laravel view into Backpack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I´m using Backpack 4.0 for Laravel to create an admin panel.

Let´s say I create vanilla Laravel view (like "foo.blade.php"). I integrate it into the menu creating a link on sidebar_content.blade.php. When I open the web page I want it to have the sidebar, header and styles from Backpack so it`s fully integrated.

What do I have to include in the view to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly, your view must extend `@extends(backpack_view('blank'))`.
I'll give a step by step of the complete operation to add a custom page to backpack so it may help others.

---

First you need to create a Controller, you can create one with `php artisan make:controller`

**CustomController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class CustomController extends Controller {

    public function custom()
    {
        return view('custom');
    }
}
```

Your view must extend `@extends(backpack_view('blank'))` and include a content section:

**custom.blade.php**

```
@extends(backpack_view('blank'))

@section('content')
    <div class="jumbotron mb-2 mt-4">
        <h1>Custom</h1>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**sidebar_content.blade.php**

```
...
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href='{{ backpack_url('custom') }}'><i class="nav-icon fa fa-archive"></i> Custom</a></li>
```

**custom.php** (routes)

```
Route::get('custom', 'CustomController@custom')->name('custom');
```

Comment: For sidebar_content.blade.php you should copy `vendor/backpack/theme-tabler/resources/views/inc/sidebar_content.blade.php` to `/resources/views/vendor/backpack/theme-tabler/inc` and then modify the copy

Comment: Actually, instead of copying a new template to the resources directory you'd be better off modifying the existent `resources/views/vendor/backpack/ui/inc/menu_items.blade.php` file and adding `<x-backpack::menu-item title="Custom" icon="la la-file" :link="backpack_url('custom')" />` to it